# Merging numbered lists in PHP

Tags: php, strpos

I have a set of items with numbers already assigned to them and am trying to fill in the gaps that the person before me left in the spreadsheet. I figured I could write a php script to do this for me yet it's placing the assigned numbers in weird spots.

Here's an example:

I have an associative array of numbers / names

```
[0] => 3502 "Scallops, Bay" [1] => 3503 "Oysters, Chesepeake" [2] => 3504 "Clams, Cherry Stone"
```

The script to order these is:

```
$d = file("list.txt");
$j=0;
for ($i=2000;$i<8000;$i++) {  //I want the codes to begin at the 2000 and end at 8000
    if (strpos($d[$j], $i) !== false) {
        echo $d[$j]."<br/>";
        $j++;
    } else {
        echo $i."<br/>";
    }
}
```

But here's what I'm getting:

2000-2056 print out fine, because they don't match [0] of $d, but then on 2057 it prints

```
2056
3502    "Scallops, Bay" 
3503    "Oysters, Chesepeake"
2059
2060
3504    "Clams, Chery Stone"
```

Then goes to print on until 2080 where it prints [3] of $d.

I'm really confused. I don't see 2057 anywhere in "3502 'Scallops, Bay'"

Should I be trying a different approach?

Comment: Have you tried [natsort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) ?

Comment: I want the other numbers in there to fill the holes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to `strpos()` can be an integer or a string; if it's an integer, it's ordinal value is used to search. From the [manual](http://php.net/strpos):

> If needle is not a string, it is converted to an integer and applied as the ordinal value of a character.

You should cast the index to a string first:

```
if (strpos($d[$j], "$i") !== false) {
```

Btw, it would be better to check whether the line *starts* with `$i` and whether `$d[$j]` is still a valid entry:

```
if (isset($d[$j]) && strpos($d[$j], "$i\t") === 0) {
```

Comment: That was it. Of course, just a silly mistake. Thank you kind sir.

Comment: I hope you know your answer would fail a lot of test cases ? Imagine `20000000000 "I love 3000 apples"` `strpos` would never be false and `strpos($d[$j], "$i") === 0` would be true .... I really need to go now see ya

Comment: @Baba Fair enough I suppose, though it seemed the range was always 4 digits. Fixed by adding one more search char.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the order. If the script reache lets say 5000 with index of 1, it won't find 3000 with index 2.

My solution:

```
$A = array('3000 abc street', '2000 something', '5000 somthing other');
function ScanFor($Number, &$A) //& is realy important
{
    foreach($A as $I => $V)
        if(strpos($Number, $V) === 0) // so it starts with it
        {
            unset($A[$I]); //We don't want it anymore
            list(, $Name) = explode(' ', $V, 1); //After Number there is always space, so we split it to 2 parts
            return $Name;
        }

    return '';
}
for($I = 2000; $I < 10000; $I++)
{
    printf("%d", $I);
    if($Name = ScanFor($I, $A))
    {
        printf("\t%s", $Name)
    }
    printf("<br>\n");
}
```

Comment: Hrm, I see where you're going. But it returned me a complete list from 2000 - 10000. Maybe I can play with this later.

Comment: My mistake, use (string) $V in strpos

Comment: This is very inefficient. Just adding a sort would already be better.

Comment: It won't because 10,20,100 would be sorted to 10,100,20.

Answer (score 0):

Try working with the file like `csv` and use `SplMinHeap` to sort

**Example:**

```
// Where to store Result
$store = new SortedValue();

// Read File
$fp = fopen("list.txt", "r");

// Read each file content
while(($data = fgetcsv($fp, 1000, " ")) !== FALSE) {
    // Filter Empty space
    $data = array_filter($data);

    // Your Filter
    if ($data[0] > 2000 && $data[0] < 8000) {
        $store->insert($data);
    }
}

// Print_r all result
print_r(iterator_to_array($store));
```

**Class Used**

```
class SortedValue extends SplMinHeap {
    function compare($a, $b) {
        return $b[0] - $a[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: `3503` , `2059` then `3504` at the end .. it does not look sorted to me :)

Comment: My dear Baba, that's the erroneous output from OP's code :) the first part of the question shows the partial contents of $d, which is in order.

Comment: Well .. i guess i need to go to bed then .. i would be able to think clearly when i wake up ..... See ya :)